# Convert dataset to dataframe from an avro file

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, spark-avro

I wrote a scala script to load an avro file, and to work with the generated data (to retrieve top contributors).
The problem is that while loading the file it gives a dataset that i can not convert to dataframe cuz it contains some complex types:

```
    val history_src = "path_to_avro_files\\frwiki*.avro"
    val revisions_dataset = spark.read.format("avro").load(history_src) 
//gives a dataset the we can see the data and make a take(1) without problems 
    
    val first_essay = revisions_dataset.map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getLong(2), row.get(3).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[Revision]].array
      .map(x=> (x.r_contributor.r_username, x.r_contributor.r_contributor_id, x.r_contributor.r_contributor_ip)))).take(1) 
//gives GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to Revision

    val second_essay = revisions_dataset.map(row => (row.getString(0), row.getLong(2), row.get(3).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]].toStream
      .map(x=> (x.getLong(0),row.get(3).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema]].map(c => (c.getLong(0))))))).take(1) 
//  gives WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
```

I tried with Encoders and Encoder using my case classes Below but didn't work

```
  case class History (title: String, namespace: Long, id: Long, revisions: Array[Revision])
  case class Contributor (r_username: String, r_contributor_id: Long, r_contributor_ip: String)
  case class Revision(r_id: Long, r_parent_id: Long, timestamp : Long, r_contributor: Contributor, sha: String)
```

I can generate the schema from my revisions_dataset is like this and it gives this:

```
root
|-- p_title: string (nullable = true)
|-- p_namespace: long (nullable = true)
|-- p_id: long (nullable = true)
|-- p_revisions: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- r_id: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- r_parent_id: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- r_timestamp: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- r_contributor: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- r_username: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- r_contributor_id: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- r_contributor_ip: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- r_sha1: string (nullable = true)
```

My goal is to have a dataframe to be able retrive the list of contributors on the revisions list and to flatten it to have a list of conributors inside the page (with the same level as the title).

Any help Please ?

Answer (score 1):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val r1 = Revision(1, 1, 1, Contributor("c1", 1, "ip1"), "sha")
val r2 = Revision(1, 1, 1, Contributor("c2", 2, "ip2"), "sha")
val r3 = Revision(1, 1, 1, Contributor("c3", 3, "ip3"), "sha")
val revisions_dataset = Seq(
  ("title1", 0L, 1L, Array(r1, r2)),
  ("title1", 0L, 2L, Array(r1, r3)),
  ("title1", 0L, 3L, Array(r2))
).toDF("p_title", "p_namespace", "p_id", "p_revisions")

val flattened = revisions_dataset.select($"p_title", $"p_id", explode($"p_revisions").alias("p_revision"))
        .withColumn("r_contributor_username", $"p_revision.r_contributor.r_username")
        .withColumn("r_contributor_id", $"p_revision.r_contributor.r_contributor_id")
        .withColumn("r_contributor_ip", $"p_revision.r_contributor.r_contributor_ip")
        .drop("p_revision")

flattened.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+----+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
|p_title|p_id|r_contributor_username|r_contributor_id|r_contributor_ip|
+-------+----+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
|title1 |1   |c1                    |1               |ip1             |
|title1 |1   |c2                    |2               |ip2             |
|title1 |2   |c1                    |1               |ip1             |
|title1 |2   |c3                    |3               |ip3             |
|title1 |3   |c2                    |2               |ip2             |
+-------+----+----------------------+----------------+----------------+
```